# Warning: mail(): SMTP server response: 451 spamhaus-xbl - Blocked

Tags: php, email, yii, wamp

Here I am trying to send email from my local machine.At that time I have got this warning.

> Warning: mail(): SMTP server response: 451 spamhaus-xbl - Blocked -
>   121.246.216.118 in C:\wamp\www\OpenInviter\example.php on line 117

I have got this error when I am adding the bellow code at top in my example.php file.

```
ini_set("SMTP","mail.domain.com");
ini_set("smtp_port","25");
ini_set('sendmail_from', 'Email@domain.com');
```

**Example.php**

```
foreach ($selected_contacts as $email=>$name)
                    mail($email,$message_subject,$message_body,$headers);
                $oks['mails']="Mails sent successfully";
```

What's the problem?

Comment: Seems like your IP address has been blacklisted by spamhaus.  I'd try sending the email to mailinator and see if it gets through.

Comment: Check out: http://hpr6.projecthoneypot.org/ip_121.246.216.118

Answer (score 2):

Spamhaus is blocking your IP as its listed @ http://cbl.abuseat.org - The reason is that you may have a virus, trojan on your computer, or possibly infected with a proxy for a spamming botnet, not good.

Once you have made sure that all the systems that use the IP are not infected visit: http://cbl.abuseat.org/lookup.cgi?ip=121.246.216.118 and click the link at the bottom. You will perhaps have to wait a week/month before all the block lists purge your ip.

If you have recently acquired the IP from your service provider, get in touch with them and ask that they change your IP.

Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

Your IP has, correctly or incorrectly, been deemed a source of spam and the SMTP server is not accepting email from you. Try a different SMTP server with which you properly authenticate, possibly a paid-for service, or try to get yourself delisted at spamhaus (good luck with that).